# Javascript if output is 0, don't print

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to not print or output if number1 is 0 or null?  using the line below with modification?

```
document.getElementById('inputTextToSave').innerHTML= parseFloat(number1*2).toFixed(3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an [`if`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) statement with a to number casted value with an [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()).

```
if (+number1) {
    document.getElementById('inputTextToSave').innerHTML = (number1 * 2).toFixed(3);
}
```

Comment: You meant +number1!

Comment: what if I have multiple numbers 
        document.getElementById('inputTextToSave').innerHTML = parseFloat(number1 * 2).toFixed(3) + "," + parseFloat(number2 * 2).toFixed(3);

Comment: then i suggest to use an array with the values, filter it (only truthy values) and map the new values (multiplication). later join the whole array with comma as separator. `result = [number1, number2].filter(a => +a).map(a => 2 * a).join(', ')`. then check if result has a truthy value with `if (result) { ` and assign the result to the element.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do it would be to surround your expression with an if. You could also use ternary expressions.

```
let result = number1 * 2
if(!result) {
    document.getElementById('inputTextToSave').innerHTML= parseFloat(result).toFixed(3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use if condition like this

```
if (number1 && parseFloat(number1) != 'NaN' && parseFloat(number1) > 0)
{
  document.getElementById('inputTextToSave').innerHTML = parseFloat(number1 * 2).toFixed(3);
}
```

Comment: it would not work for `'0'`, because the string is truthy.